# Open circuit voltage of solar panel in relation to temperature

Tags: temperature, voltage, solar-cells

How do we calculate the effect of temperature on the open circuit voltage of a solar panel?

The source: https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/solar-cell-operation/effect-of-temperature offers an answer, but i am having trouble following their reasoning.

How does one go from the equation:

$$ V_{oc} = \frac{kT}{q}\left(\ln(I_{sc})-\ln(B')-\gamma\ln(T)+\frac{qVG_0}{kT}\right) $$

to

$$ \frac{dV_{oc}}{dT} = \frac{V_{oc}-V_{G_0}}{T} - \gamma \frac{k}{q} $$

Comment: [The answer is but a Google away](https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/solar-cell-operation/effect-of-temperature). If you have run into problems understanding the calculation then feel free to ask a question here. Otherwise this veers perilously close to our [insufficient effort](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question) criterion.

Comment: @JohnRennie Apologies, I had already viewed this explanation multiple times but was having trouble understanding the reasoning behind it.